# Can't import firebase auth android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm new to React Native and have the following problem:
I import firebase auth in such way...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input } from './common';
import { auth } from 'firebase';
```

I just import it in my component and use it on log in button press.

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    state = { email: '', password: '', error: '' };

    onButtonPress() {
       debugger;
       const { email, password } = this.state;
       auth.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
           .catch(() => {
               auth.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                   .catch(() => {
                       this.setState({ error: "Authentication failed." });
                   });
          });
       debugger;
  }
```

My App module looks like this...Here I make some initialization for my app

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
```

Here I make some initialization for my app

```
    componentWillMount() {
        debugger;
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'somekey',
            authDomain: 'somedomain',
            databaseURL: 'someurl',
            projectId: 'someid',
            storageBucket: 'authentication-afcb6.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '253116783153'
        });
        debugger;
    }
```

But my emulator shows me an error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your import statement I suppose. When using firebase I always used:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.auth().<METHOD>
```

Or I think you could also import it like this if it's a named export and use it directly:

```
import {auth} from 'firebase';

auth().<METHOD>
```

Also hopefully you do know that you have to initialize your app as well using `firebase.initializeApp({<CONFIG_DATA>})`.

Comment: now it shows error 'Objects are not valid as React child'

Comment: What do you return inside your `render` method?
And a quick remark: You should never publicly post sensitive information like your firebase API key like you did above.

Comment: This seems to be allright. What about your `App.js` where you use your `LoginForm`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `react-native-firebase` library. It uses native Android and iOS SDK under the hood, instead web javascript library.

Documentation
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup

Android installation https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android

iOS installation https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of firebase you are using?

Downgrading firebase to 5.0.3 is the only solution I find and I just tried myself and it works. For reference, [here is the thread on firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/871).